# Issue with tokenizing words with NLTK in Python. Returning lists of single letters instead of words

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, tokenize, sentiment-analysis

I'm having some trouble with my NLP python program, I am trying to create a dataset of positive and negative tweets however when I run the code it only returns what appears to be tokenized individual letters. I am new to Python and NLP so I apologise if this is basic or if I'm explaining myself poorly. I have added my code below:

```
import csv
import random
import re
import string
import mysql.connector
from nltk import FreqDist, classify, NaiveBayesClassifier
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.stem.wordnet import WordNetLemmatizer
from nltk.tag import pos_tag
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize


def remove_noise(tweet_tokens, stop_words=()):
    cleaned_tokens = []
    for token, tag in pos_tag(tweet_tokens):
        token = re.sub('http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+#]|[!*\(\),]|' \
                  '(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+', '', token)
        token = re.sub("(@[A-Za-z0-9_]+)", "", token)

        if tag.startswith("NN"):
            pos = 'n'
        elif tag.startswith('VB'):
            pos = 'v'
        else:
            pos = 'a'

        lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
        token = lemmatizer.lemmatize(token, pos)

        if len(token) > 0 and token not in string.punctuation and token.lower() not in stop_words:
            cleaned_tokens.append(token.lower())
    print(token)
    return cleaned_tokens


def get_all_words(cleaned_tokens_list):
    for tokens in cleaned_tokens_list:
        for token in tokens:
            yield token


def get_tweets_for_model(cleaned_tokens_list):
    for tweet_tokens in cleaned_tokens_list:
        yield dict([token, True] for token in tweet_tokens)


if __name__ == "__main__":


with open('positive_tweets.csv') as csv_file:
    positive_tweets = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
with open('negative_tweets.csv') as csv_file:
    negative_tweets = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')

stop_words = stopwords.words('english')

positive_tweet_tokens = word_tokenize(positive_tweets)
negative_tweet_tokens = word_tokenize(negative_tweets)

positive_cleaned_tokens_list = []
negative_cleaned_tokens_list = []

for tokens in positive_tweet_tokens:
    positive_cleaned_tokens_list.append(remove_noise(tokens, stop_words))

for tokens in negative_tweet_tokens:
    negative_cleaned_tokens_list.append(remove_noise(tokens, stop_words))

all_pos_words = get_all_words(positive_cleaned_tokens_list)
all_neg_words = get_all_words(negative_cleaned_tokens_list)

freq_dist_pos = FreqDist(all_pos_words)
freq_dist_neg = FreqDist(all_neg_words)
print(freq_dist_pos.most_common(10))
print(freq_dist_neg.most_common(10))

positive_tokens_for_model = get_tweets_for_model(positive_cleaned_tokens_list)
negative_tokens_for_model = get_tweets_for_model(negative_cleaned_tokens_list)

positive_dataset = [(tweet_dict, 'positive')
                    for tweet_dict in positive_tokens_for_model]

negative_dataset = [(tweet_dict, 'negative')
                    for tweet_dict in negative_tokens_for_model]

dataset = positive_dataset + negative_dataset

random.shuffle(dataset)

train_data = dataset[:7000]
test_data = dataset[7000:]

classifier = NaiveBayesClassifier.train(train_data)

print("Accuracy is:", classify.accuracy(classifier, test_data))
```

snippet from CSV file for reference:

```
    "tweetid","username","created_at","tweet","location","place","classification"
"1285666943073161216","MeFixerr","2020-07-21 20:04:20+00:00","Overwhelmed by all the calls, msgs and tweets. I apologize for getting lost without prior notice. Did not expect to be missed with such fervor. 
I am good &amp; taking a break. Lots of love and dua's for everyone of you in #PTIFamily ❤","Pakistan, Quetta",,"positive"
```

Comment: Can you provide the first few lines from one of the tweet files?

Comment: @Yunnosch Will do. Apologies, it's a CSV file is pretty unreadable at the best of times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your tokens are from the file name ('positive_tweets.csv'), not the data inside the file. Add a print statement like below. You will see the issue.

```
positive_tweet_tokens = word_tokenize(positive_tweets)
negative_tweet_tokens = word_tokenize(negative_tweets)
print("tokens=", positive_tweet_tokens)  # add this line
```

Output from full script

```
tokens= ['positive_tweets.csv']
v
v
[('e', 3), ('v', 2), ('p', 1), ('w', 1), ('c', 1)]
[('e', 4), ('v', 2), ('n', 1), ('g', 1), ('w', 1), ('c', 1)]
Accuracy is: 0
```

Concerning the second error, replace this

```
with open('positive_tweets.csv') as csv_file:
    positive_tweets = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
with open('negative_tweets.csv') as csv_file:
    negative_tweets = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
```

with this

```
positive_tweets = negative_tweets = ""

with open('positive_tweets.csv') as csv_file:
    positive_tweets_rdr = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    all = list(positive_tweets_rdr)
    for lst in all[1:]: positive_tweets += ' ' + lst[3] #tweet column
    
with open('negative_tweets.csv') as csv_file:
    negative_tweets_rdr = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    all = list(negative_tweets_rdr)
    for lst in all[1:]: negative_tweets += ' ' + lst[3] #tweet column
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and I have now edited the code to import csv so that it can read the files. However it is now producing an error: 

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with the example code you've provided:

- nltk's `word_tokenize` takes a string, whereas you are providing a lazy csv generator. You probably want to to call `word_tokenize` on one of the fields of each row of the CSV
- your `with` statement closes the csv file before you've read any data from it

You want something like this (repeat to the negative tweets)

```
with open('positive_tweets.csv') as csv_file:
    positive_tweets = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    positive_tweet_tokens = [word_tokenize(t[3]) for t in positive_tweets]
```

PS Please also make sure the CSV file is well formatted. In the example above I'm naively slicing out the 4th field of each line, which may not be there. You'll need some error handling